# Cassandra instance by Bitnami created on Azure,connection fails

Tags: azure, solr, bitnami

I've created a VM of Apache Solr by Bitnami on Azure, specifying my username / password in the creation process .

When i run : ssh my_username@my_vm_ip it works

But in the web portal http://my_vm_ip/solr , a popup username/password appears . I use same credentials than SSH and it fails

Any idea?

Comment: Solr usually uses port `8983` (and that's also the default in the bitnami installation, while bitnami also puts Apache on port `8080`). Check those ports instead first.

Comment: my connection on ports 8983 and 8080 is blocking..no response

Comment: Those ports are usually only available on the internal network and not from the public web.

Comment: in the welcome page there is a link to my_vm_ip/solr ( i suppose this is admin page) but i couldn't pass with my credentials

Answer (score 0):

The application password generated by the Bitnami VM is generated uniquely for each VM, and [is shown on the application vm console](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/#how-to-find-application-credentials):

[image: Bitnami console from their documentation]

I'm not sure how you'd display the console login screen on Azure, but you can check the boot diagnostics log at least. The banner message is usually stored either in `/etc/issue.*` or `/etc/motd`, so I'd check that as well.

Comment: I don't have the banner to access the console with user / pass

Comment: Did you check the files where the banner is usually stored?

Answer (score 0):

The default user name is `user`.

The default password you need to ssh to your VM and check `/var/log/syslog`. Search `Bitnami`, you will get like below:

[image]

More information about this, you could check this [FAQ](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/infrastructure/solr/).

Comment: If my answer works, please don't forget to [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it will help more people here. Thanks.

Comment: The password is randomly generated, you need ssh to login to your VM and find it. I test in my lab, it works for me.